# PHP AND IF statement

Tags: php

im tring to call php page from a simple html page, and i cant find the syntax error
this is the html

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:#990000;">
<h5 align="center" style="font-family:tahoma;color:white;font-size:50px;"> Welcome! </h5> 

<form align="center" method="post" action="php_site.php"> 
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Search!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the php

```
<?php   
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && (isset($_POST['lastname'])))
{
    echo "Welcome $_POST['firstname']";
    echo "This is your last name $_POST['lastname']";  
}
else 
{
    echo "This is Empty!";
}
?>
```

thanks!

Comment: Try `echo "Welcome" . $firstname;` instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Seriously? Rely on [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)?

Comment: Was just a suggestion. That's what the comments box is for. It's up to the OP to test out the possibilities and "try" something. Not a points monger ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Right. So I suggest you leave the keys to your house on the door. It's up to you to test if that might be a problem.

Comment: My door is always open @Jon ;-) My "house" door that is. I ain't afraid of the big bad wolf hehehe

Comment: My suggestion was based on OP using `$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];` then echoing using the method in my first comment. @Jon

Answer (score 4):

The syntax of the embedded references to $_POST inside the strings is not quite right. Some ways to fix it are:

1. Wrap them in `{}` brackets:

   ```
   echo "Welcome {$_POST['firstname']}";
   echo "This is your last name {$_POST['lastname']}";
   ```
2. Or, remove the single quotes:

   ```
   echo "Welcome $_POST[firstname]";
   echo "This is your last name $_POST[lastname]";
   ```
3. Or, use string concatentation with `.` instead of embedding:

   ```
   echo "Welcome " . $_POST['firstname'];
   echo "This is your last name " . $_POST['lastname'];
   ```
4. And/or, pull the values into plain-named variables first:

   ```
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
   echo "Welcome $firstname";
   echo "This is your last name $lastname";
   ```

See the doc on [variable parsing in strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Comment: +1, or lose the single quotes around the keys. But concatenation is IMO the best.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php   
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']))
{
    echo "Welcome ".$_POST['firstname'];
    echo "This is your last name ".$_POST['lastname'];  
}
else 
{
    echo "This is Empty!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
    if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) )
    {
        echo "Welcome ".$_POST['firstname'];
        echo "This is your last name $_POST['lastname']";  
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "This is Empty!";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should set your set your `$_POST` values to variables.

```
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
```

Then, ensure that you're splitting the strings from the variables by using the concatenation punctuation `.`:

`echo "Welcome" . $firstname;` instead of `echo "Welcome $_POST['firstname']";`

Also, please post the syntax error you're getting. If PHP is breaking (white screen of death), then please add `ini_set("display_errors", "1");` in order to write errors to the screen, and then post the error output.

Comment: Unrestrained import of all $_POST variables into the global scope is a bad idea. It's taken years to [make it go away](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). Don't bring it back.

Comment: No, fair enough - I think I need some more coffee, updated the answer.